# How do you plot elliptic curves over a finite field using matlab

Tags: matlab, cryptography, matlab-figure

I need to draw an elliptic curve over the finite field F17(in other words, I want to draw some specific dots on the curve), but somehow I don't get it right.

The curve is defined by the equation:

```
y^2 = x^3 +x + 1 (mod 17)
```

I tried the way below, but it can't work.

> > > for x = 0:16, plot(x, mod(sqrt(x^3+x+1), 16),'r')', end

Can someone help ?

**[Update]**

According to Nathan and Bill's suggestions, here is a slightly modified version.

```
 x = 0:18
 plot(mod(x,16), mod(sqrt(x.^3+x+1), 16),'ro')
```

However, I feel the figure is **WRONG** , e.g.,y is not an integer when x=4 .

[image]

Comment: In your curve definition you write `mod 17` and in your matlab function `mod 16`, which one is correct?

Comment: The problem is really that you use `sqrt`. The matlab sqrt function doesn't work on finite bodies.

Comment: A plot of elliptic curve over a finite field doesn't really make sense, it looks just like randomly scattered points. To compute square roots mod a prime, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) algorithm which should not be too difficult to implement in matlab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to test all points that fulfill the equation `y^2 = x^3 +x + 1 (mod 17)`. Since it is a finite field, you cannot simply take the square root on the right side.

This is how I would go about it:

```
a=0:16  %all points of your finite field
left_side = mod(a.^2,17)  %left side of the equation
right_side = mod(a.^3+a+1,17) %right side of the equation

points = [];


%testing if left and right side are the same 
%(you could probably do something nicer here)
for i = 1:length(right_side)
    I = find(left_side == right_side(i));
    for j=1:length(I)
        points = [points;a(i),a(I(j))];
    end
end

plot(points(:,1),points(:,2),'ro')
set(gca,'XTick',0:1:16)
set(gca,'YTick',0:1:16)
grid on;
```

[image: elliptic curve]

Comment: +1, looks OK to me (notice that the points come in pairs with y coordinates y and 17-y).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was searchnig for a method to do it, it gives the right plot

Answer (score 1):

Matlab works with vectors natively.

your syntax was close, but needs to be vectorized:

```
x = 0:16
plot(x, mod(sqrt(x.^3+x+1), 16),'r')
```

Note the `.` in `x.^3`.  This tells Matlab to cube each element of `x` individually, as opposed to raising the vector `x` to the 3rd power, which doesn't mean anything.

Comment: After trying your suggestion, I found Matlab unexpectedly draws a curve rather than some dots)

Comment: Try changing `'r'` to `'ro'` in @Nathan's answer to get dots.

Comment: your mod() should be 17, not 16, since its FF_{17}.

Comment: Moreover, AFAIK, squaring in Matlab performs a real-valued square root which doesn't make sense in a finite field. Try e.g. GP/Pari for something better suited for modular/finite field arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code if you want to plot on Real numbers:

```
syms x y;
v=y^2-x^3-x-1;
ezplot(v, [-1,3,-5,5]);
```

But, for plot in modulo, at first you can write below code;

```
X=[]; for x=[0:16], z=[x; mod(x^3+x+1,17)]; X=[X, z]; end, X,
```

Then, you can plot `X` with a coordinate matrix.